# Limit output length of crypt or hash

Tags: laravel, encryption, hash, laravel-7

I was wondering if there is a way to limit the output of an `encrypted` or `hashed` value.

The case I have is, that I provide links for customers, having the `id` to an `entry` in my `db`, which contains relevant information for the receiver. Sooo... to avoid accessing to `entries` which are for someone else I am `encrypting` the `id` and append its outcome to the link. Now I am faced with the problem, that those "final links" are **extremely long** and ugly as f%!# (I actually got a lot responses, that they look highly suspicious and some of the customers didn't clicked on it, because they were afraid of being redirected to a phishing site).

However, this made me think about the option of **limiting** or individually setting the **length** of the `encryptions outcome`, like force it to contain 8 to 16 characters instead of about 250(? not sure how long they actually are). I also want to avoid using something like a redirecting page and a "self-made" URL shortener, because of the extra step I don't need. 
Currently I've spent more than two hours of googling and reading several discussions regarding this topic and yeah... I am not satisfied with the results. Most of them started about two years up to five years ago.

What else I did? 
I looked into [Laravels api](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/),  especially into `Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter`, but still no solution found.

Sooooo... I hope anyone can help me out with a solution based on laravel. I don't want to use anything else like `php_mbcrypt` itself than laravels `encrypt` or `Hash::make`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do  you really need to encrypt or just need a random string?

Comment: If there is no way to define the length of the encryptions outcome, I am going to add a column containing a random string/hash to identify the entry. But right now, I want to find out if its possible and still go on encrypting the id, to avoid adding additional steps and columns for handling this simple process. The reason why is that in some cases I don't send a request to the table the id belongs to and e. g. add it to another table as the foreign key of an entry. So I can just use decrypt and I have the id. Otherwise I would be forced to get the id first and update the 2nd table afterwards.

Comment: I suggest you do your workaround. If you really don't need encryption, just make a function that generates an alphanumeric string.

Comment: 250 characters? Encrypting a short (< 16 bytes) ID with, say, AES [yields about 40 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225459/what-is-the-length-i-must-specify-for-string-encrypted-with-aes-256-cbc-in-the-d/61226047#61226047) after base64 encoding: 16 bytes for the ciphertext block, another 16 for the IV, plus 33% base64 overhead. That being said, "to avoid access to entries which are for someone else" you need access control, not crypto. Encrypting the ID does nothing if I get my hands on someone else's link.

Comment: Encryption is variable length, depending on the size of the input plaintext.  Hashes are fixed length, no matter what the size of the input.  Make sure you are using the right process for your requirement.  A SHA-256 hash always gives 256 bits (32 bytes) of output.